# How can I iterate over all the fonts in an attributed string?

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

Can someone help me convert this to Swift:

```
NSAttributedString *attrString = self.attributedText;
NSRange rangeAll = NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length);


// First pass is to check the smallest and largest fontSize so we can prevent changes beyond that.

__block float smallestFontSize = 250;
__block float largestFontSize = 4;

[self.textStorage enumerateAttributesInRange:rangeAll options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired usingBlock:
 ^(NSDictionary *attributes, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

     // Iterate over each attribute and look for a Font Size
     [attributes enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
         if ([[key description] isEqualToString:@"NSFont"]) {
             UIFont *font = obj;
             float fontSize = font.pointSize + bySize;
             smallestFontSize = MIN(smallestFontSize, fontSize);
             largestFontSize = MAX(largestFontSize, fontSize);
         }

     }];
 }];
```

EDIT:

OK solved it. Seems the compiler just struggles to figure things out for a while and shows all kinds of syntax errors until it does.  It also seems the `attrs` variable is not in fact an `NSDictionary` but a Swift dictionary so it is necessary to cast it as `NSDictionary` before you can use `enumerateKeysandObjectsUsingBlock`, is this correct?

If there is a better way please let me know.

```
var smallestFontSize: CGFloat = 250
var largestFontSize: CGFloat = 4

self.textStorage.enumerateAttributesInRange(rangeAll, options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions.LongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired, usingBlock: {
    attrs, range, stop in

    FLOG("")
    let dict = attrs as NSDictionary

    dict.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock { key, obj, stop in

        if (key.description.isEqual("NSFont")) {
            let font = obj as UIFont
            let fontSize = font.pointSize + bySize
            smallestFontSize = min(smallestFontSize, fontSize);
            largestFontSize = max(largestFontSize, fontSize);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you have anything so far? Any specific compiler error?

Comment: have you tried this convert into swift? It's a not coding convert platform.Please put your difficulty or problem here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about translating from one language to another.

Comment: Sorry I was getting so many weird syntax errors

Comment: Casting to `NSDictionary` and then using `enumerateKeysAndObjecteUsingBlock` isn't idiomatic. You can do `for (key, value) in dict { ... }` instead.

Comment: @zneak thanks thats what I was looking for...  Post it as an answer (to a badly worded question!)  Tricky when you don't know what question to ask - but usually there is someone who can help you ask the right question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a bit redundant to iterate over all the entries in a dictionary, looking for a key.  The whole point of dictionaries is you can get the value for a key directly:

```
textStorage.enumerateAttributesInRange(rangeAll, options: .LongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) {
  attrs, range, stop in

    if let font = attrs?["NSFont"] as? UIFont {
        let fontSize = font.pointSize + bySize
        smallestFontSize = min(smallestFontSize, fontSize)
        largestFontSize = max(largestFontSize, fontSize)
    }

}
```

As you point out, `attrs` is already a Swift dictionary so why cast it back to an `NSDictionary`?  But you do need to covert the contents you get out of it to something useful, hence the `as? UIFont` call.  The `if let` guarantees all the optionals are checked (e.g. that attrs has an NSFont key and that they value is an NSFont) then you can use the font safely inside the block.

Finding min/max values is a nice use of reduce e.g. given a sequence of values with some attribute you want to find the minimum of:

```
let (minVal,maxVal) = reduce(sequence, (250,4)) {
    (min($0.0,$1.someattr),max($0.1,$1.someattr))
}
```

which you could adapt to your case (i.e. instead of `$1.someattr`, fetch the font size, then use that, returning the resulting min/max tuple from your block).  However, to do this instead of your outer `enumerateAttributesInRange` you’d have to source a sequence of attributes from `textStorage`, don’t know if that’s available.